# RuntimeError: each element in list of batch should be of equal size in BERT

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

Now i want to train bert model.
But runtimeError occured.
I don't know how to solve this error.
Please give me some help.

Here is my code.

I excute this code in
python = 3.8.10
pytorch = 1.8.0

I used IMDB datasets.

I tried change version and check data.
And the dataset is variable data.

How to handle variable data?
Please give me some tips.

```
def pretraining(
    model: MLMandNSPmodel,
    model_name: str,
    train_dataset: PretrainDataset,
    val_dataset: PretrainDataset,
):
    # Below options are just our recommendation. You can choose different options if you want.
    batch_size = 8
    learning_rate = 1e-4
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    epochs = 200 # 200 if you want to feel the effect of pretraining
    steps_per_a_epoch: int=2000
    steps_for_val: int=200

    ### YOUR CODE HERE
    # pretraining(model, model_name, train_dataset, val_dataset)
    
    MLM_train_losses: List[float] = None
    MLM_val_losses: List[float] = None
    NSP_train_losses: List[float] = None
    NSP_val_losses: List[float] = None
    MLM_train_losses = []
    MLM_val_losses = []
    NSP_train_losses = []
    NSP_val_losses = []
    
    print('')
    print(train_dataset)
    print(val_dataset)
    print('')
    
    train_data_iterator = iter(
        torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=False))
    # train_data_iterator = torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=False)
    eval_data_iterator = iter(
        torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=False))
    # eval_data_iterator = torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=2, shuffle=False)
    
    loss_log = tqdm(total=0, bar_format='{desc}')
    i = 0
    for epoch in trange(epochs, desc="Epoch", position=0):
        i += 1
        # Run batches for 'steps_per_a_epoch' times
        MLM_loss = 0
        NSP_loss = 0
        model.train()
        for step in trange(steps_per_a_epoch, desc="Training steps"):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            src, mlm, mask, nsp = next(train_data_iterator)
            mlm_loss, nsp_loss = calculate_losses(model, src, mlm, mask, nsp)
            MLM_loss += mlm_loss
            NSP_loss += nsp_loss
            loss = mlm_loss + nsp_loss
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            des = 'Loss: {:06.4f}'.format(loss.cpu())
            loss_log.set_description_str(des)

        # Calculate training loss
        MLM_loss = MLM_loss / steps_per_a_epoch
        NSP_loss = NSP_loss / steps_per_a_epoch
        MLM_train_losses.append(float(MLM_loss.data))
        NSP_train_losses.append(float(NSP_loss.data))

        # Calculate valid loss
        model.eval()
        valid_mlm_loss = 0.
        valid_nsp_loss = 0.

        for step in trange(steps_for_val, desc="Evaluation steps"):
            src, mlm, mask, nsp = next(eval_data_iterator)
            mlm_loss, nsp_loss = calculate_losses(model, src, mlm, mask, nsp)
            valid_mlm_loss += mlm_loss
            valid_nsp_loss += nsp_loss

        valid_mlm_loss = valid_mlm_loss / steps_for_val
        valid_nsp_loss = valid_nsp_loss / steps_for_val

        MLM_val_losses.append(float(valid_mlm_loss.data))
        NSP_val_losses.append(float(valid_nsp_loss.data))
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join('/home/ml/Desktop/song/HW3/hw3/',model_name + str(i)+'.pth'))


    ### END YOUR CODE

    assert len(MLM_train_losses) == len(MLM_val_losses) == epochs and \
           len(NSP_train_losses) == len(NSP_val_losses) == epochs

    assert all(isinstance(loss, float) for loss in MLM_train_losses) and \
           all(isinstance(loss, float) for loss in MLM_val_losses) and \
           all(isinstance(loss, float) for loss in NSP_train_losses) and \
           all(isinstance(loss, float) for loss in NSP_val_losses)

    return MLM_train_losses, MLM_val_losses, NSP_train_losses, NSP_val_losses
```

And this is error message

```
(hw3) ml@automl03:~/Desktop/song/HW3/hw3$ python pretrain.py
======MLM & NSP Pretraining======

<__main__.PretrainDataset object at 0x7fa72117eb80>
<__main__.PretrainDataset object at 0x7fa70d0a2a30>


<torch.utils.data.dataloader._MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter object at 0x7fa70c8b3640>
<torch.utils.data.dataloader._MultiProcessingDataLoaderIter object at 0x7fa70c8b3670>

Training steps:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                  | 0/2000 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Epoch:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                            | 0/200 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pretrain.py", line 527, in <module>
    pretrain_model()
  File "pretrain.py", line 505, in pretrain_model
    = pretraining(model, model_name, train_dataset, val_dataset)
  File "pretrain.py", line 316, in pretraining
    src, mlm, mask, nsp = next(train_data_iterator)
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 517, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1199, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1225, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 429, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 202, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 35, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 83, in default_collate
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 83, in <listcomp>
    return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
  File "/home/ml/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 81, in default_collate
    raise RuntimeError('each element in list of batch should be of equal size')
RuntimeError: each element in list of batch should be of equal siz
```

Comment: It might be an error in your PretrainDataset. Are you sure the features have all the same length?